# questions about (educational) mathematical games?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

i posted a question on

https://math.stackexchange.com/q/937887/88985

And directly somebody got one commented with:

> "not on topic"

maybe it is because i asked two questions at the same time,  but i am wondering would such a question be good for this forum ( I do think the game will have some educational value but it is mainly recreational)

Would this question ( the part about getting help) be good for this forum (i don't like the sugestion t put it on alt.math.recreational  because of the garbage their not such a good idea.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you clarify what type of answers you expect to the "getting help" part. To be more specific are you searching for volunteers *here* to help you doing this or do you search for info on resources/companies to this end.